# Add exception in stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, exception

I want to handle exception using oracle as I haven't done it before. below is my stored procedure.

```
create or replace
 PROCEDURE GET_VALID_LATLONG
 (
    P_XYCORDINATE IN VARCHAR2,
   P_SAPID IN VARCHAR2,  
   OUTR4GSTATENAME OUT SYS_REFCURSOR  
  )  
  AS
 v_counter number:=0;
 BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE;

   OPEN OUTR4GSTATENAME FOR 
 SELECT DISTINCT(R4GSTATECODE),R4GSTATENAME 
                  FROM R4G_LB.R4GSTATEBOUNDARY_EVW 
                  WHERE SDE.ST_INTERSECTS(SDE.ST_GEOMETRY('POINT 
('||P_XYCORDINATE||')', 3),SHAPE) = 1;   

 END GET_VALID_LATLONG;
```

how to handle the exception?

**UPDATE**

I added like this, is it fine when error occurs ??

```
     create or replace
 PROCEDURE GET_VALID_LATLONG
 (
  P_XYCORDINATE IN VARCHAR2,
 P_SAPID IN VARCHAR2,  
OUTR4GSTATENAME OUT SYS_REFCURSOR  
 )  
 AS
   v_counter number:=0;
BEGIN
DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE;

    OPEN OUTR4GSTATENAME FOR 
   SELECT DISTINCT(R4GSTATECODE),R4GSTATENAME 
                   FROM R4G_LB.R4GSTATEBOUNDARY_EVW 
                   WHERE SDE.ST_INTERSECTS(SDE.ST_GEOMETRY('POINT 
   ('||P_XYCORDINATE||')', 3),SHAPE) = 1;   

EXCEPTION

   WHEN OTHERS THEN
      NULL;                      

END GET_VALID_LATLONG;
```

Comment: What exception(s) do you want to handle, and what will you do when they occur? (And no, `when other then null;` is not fine...)

Comment: @AlexPoole: A simple basic exception, when something fails in the above procedure..

Comment: If it fails for any reason? You want to catch all possible exceptions and replace Oracle's error message with your  own simple version? That doesn't seem practical or useful to me. You could maybe look for specific errors that a malformed `p_xycordinate` could cause, if you could list them all; or try to validate that first.

Answer (score 0):

A list of pre-defined exceptions can be found in the Oracle docs, for example here.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/appdev.920/a96624/07_errs.htm

You can use this list of exception names in your exception clause, for example

```
WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN
    NULL;    -- whatever you wish to do here.
```